# JApplet RuntimeException

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, japplet

I've made an applet which works perfectly in the appletViewer. I've put it in a HTML code but when I open it, I get the error :

```
RuntimeException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : javax/persistence/Persistence
```

What should I do?

Comment: We need a little bit more code to see where the problem could be.  We don't have access to it, so it will be tricky to pinpoint.

Answer (score 1):

It will be necessary to add the jar containing the `Persistence` class on the run-time class-path of the applet.  To do that, put it in the same code base as the applet Jar, and reference it in a comma separated list in the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.